# How to perform a nested mount when using chroot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, mount

Note that this question is prompted by the circumstances detailed by me (as Xl1NntniNH7F) in http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/boot-failure-upon-updating-e2fsprogs-in-ubuntu-10-10-a-947328/. Thus if you could address the underlying cause of the boot failure, I would very much appreciate it.

I'm trying to replicate the environment in my ubuntu installation (where the home folder is on a separate partition) in order to run `make uninstall`. I'm using a live cd.

How to mount a dir in one partition into a directory on another mounted partition? I did `chroot /mnt/sda2` but I don't know how to mount sda3 to /home, and my various attempts didn't work. As I am unfamiliar with chroot, my approach could be wrong, so it would be great if you could suggest what I should do, given my circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bind mounts a lot with chroots, so I tend to have scripts set up which check to see if the chroot has certain dirs bind mounted already and if not, to set them up before chrooting.

For example, I have `/dev` set up as a `tmpfs` with `mdev` and `/dev/pts` mounted as a 
`devpts` filesystem:

```
$ mount | grep /dev
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw 0 0
mdev /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid 0 0
```

Then in my script I do:

```
d=/mnt/chroot
for m in dev dev/pts ; do
    grep -sq $d/$m /proc/mounts || mount --bind /$m $d/$m
done
exec chroot $d /bin/bash
```

With the current SVN Busybox trunk, it seems `/dev` is mounted twice at `/mnt/chroot/dev` and `/mnt/chroot/dev/pts` instead of `/dev` at `/mnt/chroot/dev` and `/dev/pts` at `/mnt/chroot/dev/pts`

Comment: To unmount them again, do you need to unmount both? in what order?